# Apply a wallpaper to a computer OU via AD

Tags: windows, active-directory

Every reference to applying a wallpaper to a computer via AD goes through the user.

I need to apply a wallpaper to a set of computers, a student lab specifically, and a wallpaper specific to that lab.

Students have their own AD accounts and due to that I don't have access to their accounts, just these computers.

Comment: You mean, you don't have access to apply group policy to the user objects, only to the computer objects?  Configure loopback mode.

Comment: Loopback, exactly the setting I needed. Thanks. I inherited a shared existing AD setup, it's all still a bit new to me.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use Group Policy at the Active Directory level you could specify a wallpaper, the image could either be on the local PC or accessible through a UNC path.  Doing it via GPO will mean the wallpaper cannot be changed by the user and you have control over the images.

You can achieve this by opening Group Policy Management and editing a policy to apply the setting to.

The exact path to the object will depend upon the version of GPO you are running, on my PC it is User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Desktop > Desktop > Desktop Wallpaper.

You would then enable the setting and complete the wallpaper options - Path and style.

You may find this page useful it has some screen shots and a couple different methods to set this through Group Policy: http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/best-practice-using-group-policy-to-configure-desktop-wallpaper-background/